# Facebook for Android 3.0 Maintain session

Tags: android, facebook

I have a viewpager and ActionBarSherlock. In the menu of the actionbar I placed a button "Log In" that takes me to a login screen (this is the same as the one in the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/)). This login works fine, every time I open the app, I don't need to login again. What I want is to change this "Log in" menu item to "Log out" when the session is open. But the session is alwasy null. **Not the state of the session, but the session itself**. Why?

```
   Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
   if (session == null) {

   } else {
      publishStory();
   }
```

What am I missing here? Do I need some other code, or should this be enough?

Comment: are you sure the session is opened? Can you put a log in your login screen and check the state of session?

Comment: I cannot check the state of the session, as I get a force close because the session is null.

Comment: i meant that you check the state of the session in your login screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to open the active session before you can write `Session.getActiveSession()`. And don't forget to define `session` outside:

```
Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new StatusCallback() {

                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                }
            });
session = Session.getActiveSession();
```

You can learn more about the related `openActiveSession` method here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Session